# Surfactant detaching from interface

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have large number of surfactant molecules adhering to the oil-water interface. How long (time) will it take these molecules to detach from the interface provided there is a shear stress acting on the interface? Shear stress occurs because of the fluid flow. I am looking for an estimate on the timescale.

[image]

Comment: Please provide some further details. Interface between which media? Geometry of the problem? Which surfactants? How do you apply shear stress? (Shear in fluid statics???)

Comment: I have edited with more details.

Comment: Why would the molecules detach from the surface? Are you thinking that the flow would pull them off? If so that isn't going to happen as the relative flow rate over the few nanometres the surfactant molecules occupy will be too small to have any effect.

Comment: I see...is there a way to calculate this small effect? I want to have some real numbers to compare.